# My forms data gets cleared when the submit button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

https://ghostbin.com/paste/7mkdg

I have this code, however on pressing the calculate button, it clears all the data really fast and the result isn't displayed. I can see it briefly in the address bar, and in the output box (the readonly one) but it disappears in less than a second.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <section id="main-section">
            <div class="dark-overlay">
                <div class="team-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <form class="" name="calcGravAcceleration">
                                    <div class="form-group b">
                                        <label for="inputAngVelocity1">Angular Velocity</label>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputAngVelocity1" placeholder="Angular Velocity (radians per second)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="inputRadius1">Radius</label>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputRadius1" placeholder="Radius of the spinning circle">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Gravitational Acceleration</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" id="gravAccelResult" type="text" placeholder="Readonly input here…" readonly>
                                    </div>

                                    <button onclick="calcGravAccel()" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate Gravitational Acceleration</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <script>
            function calcGravAccel(){
                var angVel = document.getElementById("inputAngVelocity1").value;
                var radius = document.getElementById("inputRadius1").value;

                var squaredAngVel = Math.pow(angVel, 2);

                var gravityAccel = squaredAngVel*radius;

                var result = document.getElementById("gravAccelResult");

                result.value="" + gravityAccel;

            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Post the code in the question itself

Comment: @CliffBurton fixed

Comment: i have put your code in working snippet just accept my edit.

Answer (score 1):

- Change your button to `input type button` to avoid the submission of your form.

---

```
<input onClick='calcGravAccel()' type='button' class="btn btn-primary" value='Calculate Gravitational Acceleration'></input>
```

- Or remove the form element.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <section id="main-section">
            <div class="dark-overlay">
                <div class="team-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <form class="" name="calcGravAcceleration">
                                    <div class="form-group b">
                                        <label for="inputAngVelocity1">Angular Velocity</label>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputAngVelocity1" placeholder="Angular Velocity (radians per second)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="inputRadius1">Radius</label>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputRadius1" placeholder="Radius of the spinning circle">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Gravitational Acceleration</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" id="gravAccelResult" type="text" placeholder="Readonly input here…" readonly>
                                    </div>

                                    <input onClick='calcGravAccel()' type='button' class="btn btn-primary" value='Calculate Gravitational Acceleration'></input>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <script>
            function calcGravAccel(e){
                var angVel = document.getElementById("inputAngVelocity1").value;
                var radius = document.getElementById("inputRadius1").value;

                var squaredAngVel = Math.pow(angVel, 2);

                var gravityAccel = squaredAngVel*radius;

                var result = document.getElementById("gravAccelResult");

                result.value="" + gravityAccel;

            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the type of the button as `type="button"`. The default type for button is `submit` which is causing your form to submit when you click which in turn is refreshing the page. Change to this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="calcGravAccel()" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate Gravitational Acceleration</button>
```

Comment: @Aklixio If it worked for you - you need to accept the answer and upvote the answers

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `<button>` on a `<form>`, the default behavior of that button is to submit the form.  You need to prevent that default behavior if you don't want it.  Get hold of the `event` parameter to the click handler, and invoke the preventDefault method.  Since you have in-line event handlers you will have to modify those slightly to pass along the event parameter.  If you used javascript to assign those handlers you wouldn't have to.

```
<button onclick="calcGravAccel(event)" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate Gravitational Acceleration</button>

...

<script>
    function calcGravAccel(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var angVel = document.getElementById("inputAngVelocity1").value;
        var radius = document.getElementById("inputRadius1").value;

        var squaredAngVel = Math.pow(angVel, 2);

        var gravityAccel = squaredAngVel*radius;

        var result = document.getElementById("gravAccelResult");

        result.value="" + gravityAccel;

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function calcGravAccel(){
                var angVel = document.getElementById("inputAngVelocity1").value;
                var radius = document.getElementById("inputRadius1").value;

                var squaredAngVel = Math.pow(angVel, 2);

                var gravityAccel = squaredAngVel*radius;

                 document.getElementById("gravAccelResult").value = gravityAccel;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <section id="main-section">
            <div class="dark-overlay">
                <div class="team-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <form class="" name="calcGravAcceleration">
                                    <div class="form-group b">
                                        <label for="inputAngVelocity1">Angular Velocity</label>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputAngVelocity1" placeholder="Angular Velocity (radians per second)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="inputRadius1">Radius</label>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputRadius1" placeholder="Radius of the spinning circle">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Gravitational Acceleration</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" id="gravAccelResult" type="text" placeholder="Readonly input here…" readonly>
                                    </div>

                                   
                                </form>
                                 <button onclick="calcGravAccel()" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate Gravitational Acceleration</button>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <script>
           
                

            
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just Add retun to the function call and return false in the function, if you dont want the form to submit**

```js
function calcGravAccel() {
  var angVel = document.getElementById("inputAngVelocity1").value;
  var radius = document.getElementById("inputRadius1").value;
  var squaredAngVel = Math.pow(angVel, 2);
  var gravityAccel = squaredAngVel * radius;
  var result = document.getElementById("gravAccelResult");
  result.value = "" + gravityAccel;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--SECTION-->
<section id="main-section">
  <div class="dark-overlay">
    <div class="team-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <form class="" name="calcGravAcceleration">
              <div class="form-group b">
                <label for="inputAngVelocity1">Angular Velocity</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputAngVelocity1" placeholder="Angular Velocity (radians per second)">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputRadius1">Radius</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputRadius1" placeholder="Radius of the spinning circle">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Gravitational Acceleration</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="gravAccelResult" type="text" placeholder="Readonly input here…" readonly>
              </div>

              <button onclick="return calcGravAccel()" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate Gravitational Acceleration</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```